# Boost Asio Multithreading From socket and STDIN

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I want simply to have a chat client that is asynchronously listening from a socket and from a `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor` assigned to stdin.

If I run this code in a single threaded application, all works fine.

If I call `io_service.run()` from 2 or more threads, the asynchronous operations from stdin, never go fine, but async readings from the socket are still executed.

here is the code:

```
MasterClient::MasterClient(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter, string nickName)
:it(iter),chatNick(nickName)
{
    this->fdIn_ = str_ptr(new boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor(io_service,::dup(STDIN_FILENO)));
    this->dirServer_ = new(connectedPeer);
    this->dirServer_->sock = socket_ptr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(this->io_service_));
    boost::asio::async_connect(*(this->dirServer_->sock), this->it,
        boost::bind(&MasterClient::connectionHandler, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
boost::asio::io_service io_service(2);
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], argv[2]);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    string nick;
    cout << "Inserire un nickname per la sessione di chat: " << flush;
    getline(cin,nick);
    MasterClient cli(io_service,iterator,nick);
cli.run();
}
```

and the MasterClient::run()

```
void MasterClient::run()
{
// Create a pool of threads to run all of the io_services.
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(this->io_service_);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_)));
    threads.push_back(thread);
}


// Wait for all threads in the pool to exit.
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
    threads[i]->join();
}
```

here i call the async readings:

```
void MasterClient::clientDelegate()
{
if(this->connectToServer())
{
    this->mainMenu();

    boost::asio::async_read_until(*fdIn_, inBuff_, '\n',
            boost::bind(&MasterClient::fdInMenuHandler,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    (*(this->dirServer_->sock)).async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(this->buff_),
            boost::bind(&MasterClient::serverHandler,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    this->dirServer_->sock));
    this->io_service_.post(boost::bind(&MasterClient::printer,this));
}else
{
    if(this->isDebugging)
        cout << "Error in ClientDelegate." << endl;
}
if(this->isDebugging)
    cout << "ClientDelegate END" << endl;
}
```

connection handler, where the clientDelegate gets called:

```
void MasterClient::connectionHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
cout << "connected" << endl;
try
{
    if(error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    else
    {
        this->dirServer_->endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint((*(this->dirServer_->sock)).remote_endpoint());
        this->clientDelegate();
    }
}catch(const boost::system::system_error& e)
{
    cerr << "Boost Exception in ConnectHandler ---> " << e.what() << endl;
    this->io_service_.stop();
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html), it's unsafe to use the same instance from multiple threads. In multithreading situations, typically the handlers are wrapped into a strand for serialisation.

In your case I don't see the point of using multiple threads for the same client connection.

Comment: According to boost asio documentation, if i call io_service.run into multiple threads, those threads are eligible to invoke the handlers. am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's safe to call the run method of the same io_service from multiple threads. However the handlers can be called concurrently, so you need to be careful. Asio provides strands to help you to serialise the handlers in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: It's not clear how your chain of handlers are in your program. Where is clientDelegate called? What does fdInMenuHandler do? It looks strange to use multi-threading with a single client connection. Why not single threaded?

Comment: It is multithreaded because the client has 3 sockets. 1 socket is for transferring text, and two sockets are for transferring files. So the idea was to use 3 threads for the connections to handle the 3 threads concurrently.

Comment: clientDelegate is called as first method after connection to a server. it is called in the connection handler. i have just added the code in the question's post. the problem isn't the concurrency. but the fact that the fdInMenuHandler never gets called. fdInMenuHandler parses the user input and does stuff, just like a menu.

Comment: In case you want to go the multi-threaded way, it's easier to use blocking sockets, then you don't need handlers. But asio's strenght is in async communication. With async communication you can perfectly handle 3 sockets in one thread. That's the purpose of the async calls.

Comment: uhm... but if i go single-threaded, can i handle a chat session while i am transferring a big file? isn't there the risk for starvation, or very long wait times for the text socket's handler to be invoked since the file's socket is continuously invoking the handler?

Comment: The fact that fdInMenuHandler never gets called doesn't proof there is not concurrency issue. `MasterClient::fdInMenuHandler`, `MasterClient::serverHandler`and `MasterClient::printer` will be called concurrently and it's easy to get a race condition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23230/discussion-between-jcm-and-martino-lessio)